# Is it possible to train a neural netowrk using a loss function on unseen data (data different from input data)?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

Normally, a loss function may be defined as
L(y_hat, y) or L(f(X), y), where f is the neural network, X is the input data, y is the target.
Is it possible to implement (preferably in PyTorch) a loss function that depends not only on the input data X, but also on X' (X != X)?

For example, let's say I have a neural network f, input data (X,y) and X'. Can I construct a loss function such that

1. f(X) is as close as possible to y, and also
2. f(X') > f(X)?

The first part can be easily implemented (PyTorch: nn.MSELoss()), the second part seems to be way harder.

P.S: this question is a reformulation of [Multiple regression while avoiding line intersections using neural nets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926325/multiple-regression-while-avoiding-line-intersections-using-neural-nets), which was closed. In the original data, input data and photos with a theoretical example are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
For instance, you can add a loss term using ReLU as follows:

```
loss = nn.MSELoss()(f(X),y) + lambd * nn.ReLU()(f(X)-f(X'))
```

where `lambd` is a hyperparameter.
Note that this corresponds to `f(X') >= f(X)` but it's easily modifiable to `f(X') > f(X)` by adding an `epsilon<0` (small enough in absolute value) constant inside the ReLU.